# Impossible to bind parameter in join clause

Tags: sql, xamarin, join, binding

I'm doing a cross platform app using Xamarin. I want to bind a ListView with a query.

My query looks like this :

```
public async Task<List<Meeting>> GetAllMeetings()
{
return await _database.QueryAsync<Meeting>("Select Client.Prenom,Meeting.Id_Client,  Meeting.DateRDV, Meeting.HourRDV,Meeting.TypePose,Meeting.IsStudent from 'Meeting'  JOIN 'Client' on Meeting.Id_Client = Client.Id");
}
```

In my ListView I'm able to bind every parameter, except Client.Prenom. I've tried only writing Prenom but nothing shows.

Here's how I bind :

```
listViewAllMeetings.ItemsSource = await App.Database.GetAllMeetings();
List<Meeting> list = listViewAllMeetings.ItemsSource as List<Meeting>;
```

And in the xaml file I do like this to bind Prenom:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Prenom}"
HorizontalOptions="Start"
TextColor="#000000" />
```

But nothing shows. Any idea ? If I bind the Id_Client it shows the correct Id...

For the record , here's my Meeting table :

```
public class Meeting {
   [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int Id_Client { get; set; }
   public String DateRDV { get; set; }
   public String HourRDV { get; set; }
   public String TypePose { get; set; }
   public bool IsStudent { get; set; }
   public bool SheCame { get; set; }
}
```

my xaml file :

```
    <ListView x:Name="listViewAllMeetings" SeparatorVisibility="Default" SeparatorColor="Silver" HasUnevenRows="True">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout
                    Orientation="Vertical">


                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding DateRDV}"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            TextColor="#FD6C9E" />
                            <Label Text="à"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            TextColor="#FD6C9E" />

                            <Label Text="{Binding HourRDV}"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            TextColor="#FD6C9E" />
                           
                        </StackLayout>
                        
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Id_Client}"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            TextColor="#FD6C9E" />
                            <Label Text="Est étudiante ?"
                            HorizontalOptions="End"
                            TextColor="#FD6C9E" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding IsStudent}"
                            HorizontalOptions="End"
                            TextColor="#FD6C9E" />

                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="{Binding TypePose}"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            TextColor="#FD6C9E" />

                    </StackLayout>

               </StackLayout>
                
            </ViewCell>

        </DataTemplate>

    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

Comment: why dont you set a breakpoint at "var ret= await _database.QueryAsync blabla" brefore you "return ret;" and examine the ret variable to see what you are returning, you'll get a clue about Prenom

Comment: i'm not sure I understood your advice..

Comment: Set breakpoint at "List<Meeting> list = listViewAllMeetings.ItemsSource as List<Meeting>;", examine the "listViewAllMeetings.ItemsSource" variable to check if you really have Prenom as expected

Comment: I only have the Meeting fields, so instead of having Prenom, I have Id_Client, any idea on how to fix it ?

Comment: post xaml code as well

Comment: Side note: Do not make a habit of putting identifiers, like table names, in single quotes. Single quotes in Standard SQL are used for string (and other) literals, not identifiers. You'll get errors in other DBMS if you single quote identifiers.

Comment: @Blu posted my xaml file

Comment: The Xamarin.Forms data binding links a pair of properties between two objects. In your case, the binding is bound between Meeting class and the listView. The view cannot get class from the 'Client' class. If you want to set binding the 'Prenom' to the listView, try using a value converter to convert the value from 'Id_Client' property to 'Prenom' property. Tutorial:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters

Comment: Check the code: `public class BindingValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int id = (int)value;//the id is the value of id_client, you could get the Prenom value from database with value
        var prenom = ...;//get the Prenom value
        return prenom;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

this line will take the results of your Query and map it into a `Meeting` object

```
return await _database.QueryAsync<Meeting>("Select Client.Prenom,Meeting.Id_Client,  Meeting.DateRDV, Meeting.HourRDV,Meeting.TypePose,Meeting.IsStudent from 'Meeting'  JOIN 'Client' on Meeting.Id_Client = Client.Id");
```

your `Meeting` class does not have any property that `Client.Prenom` can be mapped onto

Comment: yes I understood that after, but how should I change to get Client.Prenom ?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting ItemSource on your List,

> Just edit this line in your xaml page, keep rest things as same

```
 <ListView x:Name="listViewAllMeetings" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Meetings}" SeparatorVisibility="Default" SeparatorColor="Silver" HasUnevenRows="True">
```

Just add this to your parent list `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Meeting}"`. I guess it will work for you.

Bind the `Meeting` with the query in your ViewModel.

EDIT ---------

```
        //initialize these variables in your xaml.cs file
        ObservableCollection<Meeting> _meetings { get; set; } 
        ObservableCollection<Meeting> Meetings { get { return _meetings} set { _meetings = value; NotifyPropertyChanged() } }

        //Add this in your constructor of xaml.cs file
        Meetings = App.Database.GetAllMeetings(); //Add
```

> Correct your query as suggested by `Jason`

Add the `Prenom` refrence in Meeting.

```
public class Meeting {
   [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int Prenom{ get; set; }           //ADD here
   .....
}
```

Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: How did you Bind `Meeting` in ViewModel? pls show that

Comment: I'm not using ViewModel.. should I ?

Comment: no issue with view model, just show how you binding it

Comment: I'm not sure I understood... i'm binding in the xaml file (code above)

Comment: i guess you are new to Xamarin forms

Comment: let me find a better way to explain it

Comment: I'm indeed new to Xamarin forms sorry for my miss understandings

Comment: @Hector try the new thing

Comment: what does it mean "read only property to your model?" and also, Meetings is an ObservableCollection and my query GetAllMeetings returns a List..

Comment: and where does NotifiyPropoertyChanged comes from ?

Comment: you must need to read about NotifiyPropoertyChanged (); over google, don't go further without knowing this thing. Its really good.

Comment: Change observablecollection with LIST & remove NotifiyPropoertyChanged() just for now and give it a try.. but try using observablecollection instead of a list in the future for the better practice... if you find it helpful & if it solves your issue, give it an upvote & mark it as correct.

Comment: nothing changed, i'll try to figure it with another way, thank you anyway !

Comment: none of this has any bearing IF `Prenom` isn't being populated from your query.  Have you verified that this field in your model actually contains the correct value from the query?  Until you fix that nothing else will change.

Comment: @Jason i still have doubts that he's understanding what you are trying to explain. Need to provide him some links about basics  for better understanding of concepts.